# Should I always exclude $\arg(0)$ in an Argand diagram?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'd like to ask you about the convention. I know that $\arg(0)$ is undefined and the question is:

1. Should I always exclude the $(0,0)$ point in an Argand diagram?
2. Why is the $z_0$ point excluded on the second image?

> [image]
>
> $\alpha<\arg z\le\beta$
>
> [image]
>
> $\alpha<\arg(z-z_0)\le\beta$

Comment: $z_0$ is omitted because to include it, you’d be talking about $\arg(0)$.

Comment: @Lubin, thank you. I was just curious about the starting point. In this case $z_0$ can be anywhere and should be always excluded?

Comment: If your formula involves $\arg(0)$ when you plug $z_0$ in for $z$, yes.